# Are two hard disks interchangable in a notebook computer?

Tags: hard-drive, operating-systems

My current original hark disk has Windows Vista installed on it. I am thinking of replacing it with a bigger hard disk with Windows 7 installed.

Can I interchange these two hard disks later on?

Answer (score 1):

short answer : probably
long answer: generally yes, if you swap sata with sata, and pata with pata. some hard drives (dell comes to mind) have a non standard interface connected to a standard one.